# unit testing windows phone application with sdk 7.1

Tags: unit-testing, windows-phone-7, nunit, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I have troubles setting up unit test framework for windows phone sdk 7.1
there seems to be two possibilities: 
- proposed by Jeff Wilcox 
- to use NUnitTestRunner

in the first case I have the following error: "Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key typeNameConverter". mister Internet suggests I redefine IValueConverters.
If someone can upload a sample project that has couple of dummy tests and work on Emulator

in the second case. after applying Linux experience and building your own NUnitTestRunner.dll and applying it to your project, I still seem to have a black screen on my Emulator instead of the test-run. I used [this](http://cisforcoder.wordpress.com/2011/04/05/getting-started-with-unit-testing-using-nunit-test-runner-for-wp7/) walk-through to set it up

any help is appreciated. thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK the updated assemblies provided by Jeff Wilcox on this blog - [Updated Silverlight Unit Test Framework binaries–compatible with the Mango phone tools beta](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2011/06/updated-ut-mango-bits/) fixes up the error regarding the value converter.

I have a rather incomplete tests project you can view in [Compiled Experience Phone Toolkit](https://bitbucket.org/nigel.sampson/compiled-experience-toolkit/src).

Hope this helps.